# Can't download file using URLDownloadToFile in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-server-2012-r2

This question is about the usage of `URLDownloadToFile` API.

I am using `URLDownloadToFile` in Visual C++ MFC application. On Windows server 2008, the program is working fine.

Sample code:

```
// invalidate cache, so file is always downloaded from web site
// (if not called, the file will be retrieved from the cache if
// it's already been downloaded.)
DeleteUrlCacheEntry(aCSVDownloadURL);

CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
IBindStatusCallback* pBindStatusCallback = NULL;
callbackHandler.QueryInterface(IID_IBindStatusCallback,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBindStatusCallback));

HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(
    NULL,   // A pointer to the controlling IUnknown interface
    DownloadURL,
    FileName, // Filename to save the downloaded file in local
    0,      // Reserved. Must be set to 0.
    pBindStatusCallback // Callback interface to catch the download response; basically the file name
);

if (hr == S_OK)
{
    cout << "Download OK" << endl;
}
else if (hr == E_OUTOFMEMORY)
{
    cout << "The buffer length is invalid, or there is insufficient memory to complete the operation." << endl;
} else if (hr == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE)
{
    cout << "The specified resource or callback interface was invalid." << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Other error" << endl;
}
```

But when run the app in Windows Server 2012 R2, I get the below error:

> Error code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE
>   Description: The specified resource or callback interface was invalid.

Have done googling for few hours, but still no luck. It would be very much appreciated if there is a solution.

The program is created using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Is "*blow error*" a typo, or is that actual term for this kind of error...?

Comment: oh :( typo, will update soon.

Comment: You need to show the code that calls the function.

Comment: @AlexK.: Thanks for your comment. Added the sample code in description.

Comment: Just for clarification.
Which .NET Framework is required for URLDownloadToFile API?
From documentation its not clear.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Some kind of firewall blocking your connection, would be my guess. [The error means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145.aspx#INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) "The download has failed (the connection was interrupted)." `URLDownloadToFile` has nothing whatsoever to do with .NET

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked the Firewall settings and also added the app in Inbound rules. But still facing the same error. Would you please suggest that what kind of Firewall blocking I should check?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have a similar issue with URLDownloadToFile on Windows 7 x64 machine and it seems to work after setting the callback interface to NULL; synchronous vs asynchronous.